# How to get user ID by username/mention - Telegram bot api

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, nim-lang

I am trying to create my own admin bot that can handle a lot of the admin stuff, such as muting users... Currently I can mute users by tagging/replying to their message, but I also want to be able to mute a user by @mentioning (such as @Netsu) them, but how do I get a users ID via their username? I don't see any way to get it from the [API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api), or did I just miss it?

If you are interested, I'm using Nim + Telebot.

Comment: I've been playing a bit, and only found that sometimes "getChat?chat_id=12345" returns the ID with the field "username" (sometimes it doesn't). I guess you need to store "id->username" and then use that data to act (e.g. "ban @username" -> find stored "username" ID -> ban ID).